# Global Error handling in Angular 6 application

Tags: angular, http, error-handling

How can we do global error handling in angular 6?

I know we can use interceptor to handle the error at one place but in my case when one of my page loads I sent multiple HTTP async requests on `ngOnit()` to the server and in case all of the request fails I need to show only one dialog box instead of showing a dialog box for each request.

How can we do it in angular 6?

Below is the code snippet:

```
export class HttpErrorInterceptor  implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
    return next.handle(request)
       .pipe(catchError( (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {   
            let errMsg = '';

            // Server Side Error
            errMsg = `Error Code: ${error.status},  Message: ${error.message}`;

            showDialog(errMsg)      
          })
       )
  }
}
```

If I use `showDialog(errMsg)` as above, it will pop up a dialog box for each HTTP failure.

Please suggest a better way.

Comment: It's up to you: either display a list of errors in the dialog, or only display the last error, or only display the first one until the dialog is closed. Choose the strategy you prefer, and start writing code to implement it.

Comment: Code snippet shared.Please help

Comment: Well, change the `showDialog` method (or call another one), in order to not show the dialog if it's already opened, or to replace the message it's displaying if it's already opened, or to add a message to the list of messages that it's displaying if it's already opened.

Comment: I am using angular material dialog. Can you share the logic to not show the dialog if it's already opened with the angular material dialog box?

Comment: `if (!this.opened) { this.showDialog(); this.opened = true; } // TODO make sure this.opened is set to false when the dialog is closed. Look at the documentation for how to do that.`

Comment: Not sure, but probably you can implement a [Singleton service](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services) where each component can send it's success or errors when finished loading .... to the central service which waits to receive all information from each component to proceed ....